# How to keep keys/values based on the input?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to set key and values into a single dictionary based on my input.

```
keys = ['user1', 'user2', 'usr3', 'usr4', 'usr5', 'usr6']
values = ['apple', 'banana', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'red2', 'red3']
```

If user specify repeat same value twice for a key

```
{'user1': 'apple', 'user2': 'apple', 'usr3': 'banana', 'usr4': 'banana', 'usr5':'white', 'usr6': 'white'}
```

If user specify repeat 3 times value for a key

```
{'user1': 'apple', 'user2': 'apple', 'usr3': 'apple', 'usr4': 'banana', 'usr5':'banana', 'usr6': 'banana'}
```

Comment: How would "user specify" these things?  How did you attempt to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions here. The first is how to construct a dictionary from a list of keys and a list of values. For this, you can use the fact that the `dict()` constructor accepts a list of (key, value) pairs. For example:

```
>>> dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)]) 
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

If your keys and values are in separate lists, you can use the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to pair up keys and values. Note that `zip()` truncates the result to the length of the shortest argument.  For example:

```
>>> dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

The second question is how to duplicate each value a given number of times. There are multiple ways to achieve that but probably the easiest is using a list comprehension. For example, if you have a list of 5 values and you want to duplicate each value 3 times, you could write:

```
>>> [x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] for _ in range(3)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Now combining these two ideas yields a solution like this:

```
dict(zip(keys, (v for v in values for _ in range(3))))
```

Note that I used a generator expression (`(..)`) instead of a list comprehension (`[..]`) for the values, so that instead of generating the full list of values, only the part that will be used is generated. (Remember that `zip()` will stop when it runs out of keys.)

Comment: Another easy way to repeat each value: use [more_itertools.repeat_each](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.repeat_each)

Answer (score -1):

```
keys = ['user1', 'user2', 'usr3', 'usr4', 'usr5', 'usr6']
values = ['apple', 'banana', 'white', 'black', 'red', 'red2', 'red3']

result = {}
value_index = 0

for key in keys:
    if key in result:
        result[key].append(values[value_index])
    else:
        result[key] = [values[value_index]]

    value_index += 1
    if value_index == len(values):
        value_index = 0

final_result = {key: values[0] if len(values) == 1 else values.pop(0) for key, values in result.items()}

print(final_result)
```